# Check for data within a json object in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, list, api

I'm using the JSON API found at https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/jhucsse. It stores the data as a list of JSON objects. I'm making a small website to allow users to scroll through a list, pick their country and province, and view data for that country/province. I'm using JQuery for this, here is my code so far:

```js
const apiLink = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/jhucsse"

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#SubmitButton").click(function() {
        country_value = $('#country_picker').val() //Gets the value of the country_value select list in index.html


        $.get(apiLink, function(data,status){
          console.log(data[0]) // Placeholder code that prints the first JSON object in the list to the console
          // Other code here
        })
      
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = TestHTML; // Fills the 'output' div element with the output of the program
    });
});
```

How would I approach this problem?

Comment: *"I use this JSON", "I have this code", "How would I approach this problem?"* ...what problem?

Comment: And AJAX is asynchronous, you should build the HTML **inside** the AJAX callback. So basically move `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = TestHTML;` **into** the $.get function body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't need jQuery. You can use the [**Fetch API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- Get the data as **JSON**
- Since the JSON data is an Array, use the prototype [**.forEach()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to extract data for each *country* object
- Use [**.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to construct a HTML string to be appended to the table's TBODY
- Use [**.addEventListener**()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach an `"input"` Event to your `#search` input Element
- Use the String [**.includes**()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to check if any row has the searched value, and if a value does not matches set the `hidden` property to that TR element

Here's an example:

```js
const el = (sel, el) => (el || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, el) => (el || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

const elSearch = el("#search");
const elTable = el("#table");
const elTbody = el("tbody", elTable);
let elsTr;

const apiLink = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/jhucsse";

const row = (item) => `<tr>
  <td>${item.country}</td>
  <td>${item.province || ""}</td>
  <td>${item.county || ""}</td>
  <td>${item.stats.confirmed || "-"}</td>
  <td>${item.stats.deaths    || "-"}</td>
  <td>${item.stats.recovered || "-"}</td>
</tr>`;

const build = (data) => {
  elTbody.innerHTML = data.reduce((html, item) => html += row(item), "");
  elsTr = els("tr", elTbody);
  elSearch.addEventListener("input", search);
};

const search = () => {
  const value = elSearch.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  elsTr.forEach(elTr => {
    const content = elTr.textContent.toLowerCase();
    const match = content.includes(value);
    elTr.hidden = value && !match;
  });
};

fetch(apiLink).then(res => res.json()).then(build);
```

```css
.sticky-thead {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 140px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sticky-thead table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.sticky-thead td,
.sticky-thead th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
}

.sticky-thead thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
<div class="sticky-thead">
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Province</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Confirmed</th>
        <th>Deaths</th>
        <th>Recovered</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate a list, just do a for-loop? `data` is just an array of objects with properties.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   data[i].country // access the country
   data[i].stats.deaths //access the deaths
}
```